# Buttons are not displaying until mouse hover on it in java

Tags: java, swing

JButtons are not displayed until or unless I hover on the buttons.

```
package paint;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author Rehan Shakir
 */

public class PaintFrame extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener,ActionListener
{
  private int x=0; 
  private int y=0;
  private final JButton red,yellow,blue,green;
 private final JPanel p;
  //private final  JLabel l;
  private final  Container c; 
  private Color color;
  public PaintFrame()
  {

     setTitle("Paint");
     setSize(800,600);
     setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     //setLayout(new FlowLayout());



     p = new JPanel();
     p.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));



     red = new JButton("Red");
     red.setBackground(Color.red);
     p.add(red);

     yellow = new JButton("Yellow");
     yellow.setBackground(Color.yellow);
     p.add(yellow);



     blue = new JButton("Blue");
     blue.setBackground(Color.blue);
     p.add(blue);

     green = new JButton("Green");
     green.setBackground(Color.green);
     p.add(green);

     red.addActionListener(this);
     yellow.addActionListener(this);
     blue.addActionListener(this);
     green.addActionListener(this);


     c = this.getContentPane();
     c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     JLabel l = new JLabel("Drag the mouse to draw",JLabel.RIGHT);
     c.add(l,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     c.add(p,BorderLayout.WEST);

     c.addMouseMotionListener(this);
     setVisible(true);     

  }


    @Override
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e )
      {
         x= e.getX();
         y= e.getY();
         repaint();

      }
  @Override
      public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
      {

      }
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
          String s = e.getActionCommand();
          if(s.equals("Red"))
              color = Color.red;
          else if(s.equals("Yellow"))
              color = Color.yellow;
          else if(s.equals("Blue"))
              color = Color.blue;
          else if(s.equals("Green"))
              color = Color.green;
          else
              color = Color.BLACK;

      }



  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
     g.setColor(color);
      g.fillOval(x, y, 4, 4);
  }

}
```

**Main Class**

```
public class Paint {
      package paint;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        PaintFrame Jf = new PaintFrame();

    }

}
```

When I execute this program only the first JButton is displayed on the screen. I have to hover on other buttons so that they can be displayed on the screen.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Immediately from your title, I could guess that you weren't calling the super's painting method in your override -- and I was right:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
   // ********** no super call here! *******
   g.setColor(color);
   g.fillOval(x, y, 4, 4);
}
```

By not doing this, you're not allowing the component to do its important house-keeping painting, including the painting of child components and removal of "dirty" pixels

This:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
   super.paint(g);
   g.setColor(color);
   g.fillOval(x, y, 4, 4);
}
```

will likely fix things

---

Having said this, I must add:

- Don't paint directly in a JFrame
- Do paint in the `paintComponent` method override of a class that extends JPanel instead
- Call the `super.paintComponent(g)` in your JPanel's overridden method (for the same reasons).

Example using a BufferedImage:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainPaintPanel extends JPanel {
    private PaintPanel paintPanel = new PaintPanel();

    public MainPaintPanel() {
        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        paintPanel.addMouseListener(myMouse);
        paintPanel.addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 3, 3));
        addColorButton(btnPanel, Color.RED, "Red");
        addColorButton(btnPanel, Color.YELLOW, "Yellow");
        addColorButton(btnPanel, Color.BLUE, "Blue");
        addColorButton(btnPanel, Color.GREEN, "Green");        

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(paintPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    }

    class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        Point p1 = null;

        private void moveOval(MouseEvent e) {
            if (p1 == null) {
                return;
            }
            Point p2 = e.getPoint();
            paintPanel.addLine(p1, p2);
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            p1 = e.getPoint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            moveOval(e);
            p1 = e.getPoint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            moveOval(e);
            p1 = null;
        }
    }

    private void addColorButton(JPanel btnPanel, Color color, String name) {
        JButton button = new JButton(new ButtonAction(name, color));
        button.setBackground(color);
        btnPanel.add(button);
    }

    class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {        
        private Color color;

        public ButtonAction(String name, Color color) {
            super(name);
            this.color = color;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            paintPanel.setOvalColor(color);
        }
    }


    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MainPaintPanel mainPanel = new MainPaintPanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Painting GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class PaintPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 800;
    private static final int PREF_H = 600;
    private static final int OVAL_WIDTH = 4;
    private static final Stroke BASIC_STROKE = new BasicStroke(OVAL_WIDTH);
    private BufferedImage img;
    private Color ovalColor;

    public PaintPanel() {
        img = new BufferedImage(PREF_W, PREF_W, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    }

    public void addLine(Point p1, Point p2) {
        if (img != null && ovalColor != null) {
            Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
            g2.setStroke(BASIC_STROKE);
            g2.setColor(ovalColor);
            g2.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
            g2.dispose();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void setOvalColor(Color ovalColor) {
        this.ovalColor = ovalColor;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (img != null) {
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works all the buttons appeared but by calling super.paint it changes the functionality of my program

Comment: @rehanshakir: changes -- how so?

Comment: @rehanshakir: also, nowhere in your question do you tell us your program's desired behavior, and so there is no way for us to guess what functionality my answer disrupts.

Comment: Basically my program is a simple paint program when I call super.paint in method paintComponent and execute my program only a dot appears that follows my mouse pointer nothing is drawn on the frame.

Comment: @rehanshakir: this is key information that needs to be in the main question. If you want to draw, then you will want to draw lines, not dots, else fast mouse drags will show up as dots. You need to either draw to a BufferedImage or create an ArrayList of these lines and draw them with a for-loop in your paintComponent method.

Comment: Thanks, I understand